# sql: question regarding query optimization

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, indexing

I have the following two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Test_Main
    (
      [ID] INT IDENTITY ,
      [TypeID] INT ,
      [BookID] INT
    )

CREATE TABLE Test_Second
    (
      [TypeID] INT ,
      [BookID] INT ,
      [Value] INT,

    )

INSERT  INTO Test_Main(TypeID, BookID)
   SELECT 1, 10
   UNION
   SELECT 2, 31
   UNION
   SELECT 3, 51
   UNION
   SELECT 4, 81

INSERT INTO Test_Second(TypeID, BookID, Value)
   SELECT  1, 0, 30
   UNION
   SELECT  2, 31, 45
   UNION
   SELECT  3, 51, 66
   UNION
   SELECT  4, 0, 22
```

and I have the following query :

```
SELECT  
    ID ,
    Test_Main.TypeID ,
    Test_Main.BookID
FROM
    Test_Main
INNER JOIN 
    Test_Second ON Test_Main.[TypeID] = Test_Second.[TypeID]
WHERE   
    Test_Main.BookID = CASE WHEN (Test_Main.BookID = 2 OR Test_Main.BookID = 3) 
                                THEN Test_Second.BookID
                            ELSE Test_Main.BookID
                       END
```

This query is giving the following output:

```
ID          TypeID      BookID
----------- ----------- -----------
1           1           10
2           2           31
3           3           51
4           4           81
```

Now when my table has million rows I suspect my case clause will cause the performance issue. How can I optimize the query to use index seek. What should be the index for the above query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have the appropriate indices in place:

- The column `TypeID` should be indexed on both tables (since it's used in the JOIN condition)
- The column `Test_Main.BookID` needs to be indexed since it's used in the WHERE clause

With those three indices in place, I believe your query should work quite nicely, even with lots of rows in the tables!

Comment: Do you think a compoun index on `(TypeID, BookID)` would be used (and help improve efficiency)?

Comment: @ypercube: it would be used for queries on `TypeID` - but adding the `BookID` doesn't really help, I would think; this compound index could **not** be used for queries using `BookID` alone....

Answer (score 0):

(Question: Are you sure you don't mean `TypeID` instead of `BookID` in this part?):

```
... WHEN (Test_Main.TypeID = 2 OR Test_Main.TypeID = 3)
```

---

Your query is equivalent to:

```
SELECT  
    ID ,
    Test_Main.TypeID ,
    Test_Main.BookID
FROM
    Test_Main
INNER JOIN 
    Test_Second ON Test_Main.[TypeID] = Test_Second.[TypeID]
WHERE   
    ( Test_Main.BookID IN (2,3) 
      AND Test_Main.BookID = Test_Second.BookID
    )
  OR Test_Main.BookID NOT IN (2,3)
```

Besides indexes, you can check the execution plans of this version too (just in case, I'm not sure how well `CASE` clauses can be optimized).